# Highscore with jQuery.ajax: How to Initialize / Scope Issue

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm quite a newbie concerning JS, so this may be a stupid question...

I try to do a Highscore Master/Detail chart (see sample http://jsfiddle.net/VhqaQ/). The `data` array should be filled with a jQuery.ajax call:

```
$(function () {

    var masterChart,
        detailChart,
        data=[],
        chatter=[],
        indizies=[];

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php',
            data: 'type=1363435001',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
                data = json.range;
                scatter =  json.scatter;
                indizies = json.indizies;

            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
               alert('Status: ' + status +' Error: ' + error);
            }
        });

        // create the master chart
        function createMaster() {
            masterChart = new Highcharts.Chart({

            .......
                series: [{
                    type: 'columnrange',
                    name: 'Intervall',
                    pointInterval: 1,
                    pointStart: 0,
                    data: data
                }],
            });
        }

            ........

        createMaster();
   });
});
```

But like this the chart stays empty. Is this a scope issue for the `data` array? Or is `data` not initialized yet when `new Highcharts.Chart( ...)` is called?

I tested the ajax part - data is filled properly. So this is not the issue...

Maybe I should put the ajax call somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call createMaster() in the callback of your $.ajax call and pass it the data.
You are currently assuming that at initialization of the ajax call that the data has been returned, which most likely not the case.  Placing the function call inside of the callback ensure that your data is present.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php',
    data: 'type=1363435001',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
        data = json.range;
        scatter =  json.scatter;
        indizies = json.indizies;

        createMaster(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert('Status: ' + status +' Error: ' + error);
    }
});

// create the master chart
    function createMaster(data) {
        masterChart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        .......
            series: [{
                type: 'columnrange',
                name: 'Intervall',
                pointInterval: 1,
                pointStart: 0,
                data: data
            }],
        });
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand why data doesn't have global scope... It's declared on the same level as createMaster and the ajax call.

Comment: @rantanplan  I didn't see your initialization of the variables before.  I apologize.  I must have accidentally scrolled down too far.  That said, just because the variable is present doesn't mean that the data set has been returned yet.  The safest course of action is to call your method after you are 100% certain that your call has resolved, which is in the callback of your ajax asynchronous call.  I'll update my answer to remove that offending line.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I understand: It's a timing issue...!

Comment: @rantanplan Exactly :)  It might be called a "race condition".  Either way, in asynchronous programming, we use callbacks to instruct our code not to worry about resolving that particular function until it's request has resolved.